# ¿Cómo puedo llamar a una función de un archivo de Python al hacer click en un botón de la template en Django?

Tags: python, django

Necesito que al hacer click en un botón de mi plantilla, se lance una función de un archivo de python de manera que me coja unos datos y me renderice otra plantilla,

¿alguien sabe como se puede hacer esto?

Comment: Buenas G310, puedes mostrar tu codigo actual y explicar por qué no te funciona? Te da errores de consola? te da problemas de algun tipo? Un saludo

Comment: No tengo código desarrollado sobre esto, es que no se como se podría hacer y no encuentro nada que me ayude por el momento. @lois6b

Comment: Entonces te sugiero que primero investigues más y trates de implementarlo. Si no tienes codigo que arreglar, no podemos ayudarte. Como ya tienes 20 de reputacion, puedes entrar en el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) y preguntar más coloquialmente por ahi.. pero a estas horas está bastante muerto. Un saludo

Comment: Vale, gracias @lois6b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Filtrar por Hooks" name="filtrarHooks"/>
</form>
```

En el action del form hay que apuntar a la ruta que lanza la función que queremos.La ruta se podrá ver en el archivo de urls.py.

Con un formulario como este en mi plantilla, la solución que he encontrado finalmente es esta:

```
if "filtrarHooks" in request.POST:
```

Con este código en la función del archivo python, compruebas si te llega el valor del input.